# XML parsing in SVN

Tags: xml, svn

I am in the processes of learning how SVN works. I found that the source code for SVN makes extensive use of XML parsers (eg: expat and libxml). Why would SVN need an XML parser? Is this just for logging purposes or if the SVN directory structure stored as an XML document?

Comment: May be svn use the libxml for log output to xml format ?